# How to diff against previous revision with P4 command

Tags: diff, perforce

I tried this command to get the changed files and their revisions:

```
p4 describe -s <changelistNum>
```

I want to get the detailed changes against the previous revisions. For example, the file //depot/xxx/myproject/a.js is changed from #3 to #4 in this submit, and I want to see the changed contents. So I tried this command, but it only showed a brief description:

```
p4 diff2 -df //depot/xxx/myproject/a.js#3 //depot/xxx/myproject/a.js#4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want describe to show you the file differences, simply omit the -s flag.

Describe -s means "short" describe, and it omits the diffs .

Without -s, describe shows the file diffs.

There are other flags to describe, too. Do "p4 help describe" to find out about all the flags your server supports.